# Generate qr-code which is URL of user-selected-Model's Controller#Show in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, qr-code

Looking for general guidance on design/architecture of this in rails.

Use-case / Goal:

User can go to website, and search for a list of `Mortgages` (the model in the database):

1. User will select a single mortgage
2. After selecting, they will receive a QR Code on the screen which is the URL for the `MortgageController#show` method for the particular `Mortgage` that was chosen.

**To emphasize:** When they select the mortgage, they won't go to the `MortgageController#show`, rather they need to be returned a page containing a QR code which represents the URL to the proper `MortgageController#show` for the mortgage they selected.

**Context:**  The QR-code page will be printed, scanned --along with the physical mortgage files-- into a document imaging system. The document imaging system will parse the QR Code, hitting the `MortgageController#show`, receiving JSON "describing"/representing that particular scanned `Mortgage`. (Using Qr-code leading to JSON, rather than the raw JSON, as scanners do better with QR-codes than text.).

I think I pretty well understand the `MortgageController#show` side of things -- it's just returning a JSON representation of the model `Mortgage`.

**Things get fuzzy:**

I imagine where the user will search/select a mortgage could be the `MortgageController#index` method.

But if I have a `get QR Code` link for each `Mortgage`, should it hit a custom method on the `MortgageController` like `qr_code`, which determines the proper URL which needs to be made into a QR code and returned?

I'm not sure how to organize the part that generates a QR Code pointing to the `show` method of `MortgageController`, and how the plumbing of this will work. Is it possible to know from a list of `Model`s, which one was selected from a link, or `form_for` tag, if that link doesn't go to the standard `show` method of the controller? (Because I cannot use that method... that's the one that will be returning JSON!)

I'm pretty mixed up about this, and am new to Rails. Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer all of your questions:

1. Yes, the action listing the mortgages should be `MortgageController#index`
2. For the QR view, you have several choices. One way, probably the most REST-pure, you'll call `MortgageController#show` on that particular mortgage, using `format: :qr`, a `MimeType` you'd define for the occasion (the URL would be `/mortgages/2.qr` and the path in the form_for block would be `mortgage_path(mortgage, format: :qr)`. In the controller side, you'd handle this using the [`respond_to |format|`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods/respond_to) structure.
3. Another simpler option would be to define a non-REST action to present the QR: `MortgageController#qr_code`. That action you'd define like this on your `routes.rb` file:

> ```
> resources :mortgages do
>   get :qr_code, on: :member
> end
> ```

4. As a bonus track (not included in your question), you can use [rqrcode_png gem](https://github.com/DCarper/rqrcode_png) to generate and print the QR codes in the `/mortgage/3/qr_code` view.

Comment: Thanks for your help! For `3.`, I'm confused as to what `:member` is, or why a resource nested within `resources :mortgages` in `routes.rb` is necessary... What would the `form_for` used in the `MortgageController#index` view look like for that example? Also, for `4.`, this won't get in the way of `MortgagesController#show`? Would the `form_for` in `MortgagesController#index` view link directly to `mortgage/3/qr_code` -- i.e. what controller would it hit? ... Sorry, I'm a newb so I'm full of confusion

Comment: ... on second thought I think I like `2.` mayhaps... What would the `form_tag` look like to send the proper `MimeType` argument along with the correct `Mortgage` model?

Comment: Take a look at the Routing part of the Rails guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in order to understand the routing setup in 3. I updated both 2. and 3. to answer your questions.

Comment: thanks a bunch, I ended up going the `2.` route, and using `rqrcode_png gem` in the controller to create a QR code from the model's JSON'd data, and to display the QR code as a simple image in a view `show.qr.erb`